# Start SSMS for SQL 2012 using CMD

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, ssms-2012

I have installed SQL 2008 R2, and then I installed SSMS for that server.

After a few months, I've installed SQL Server 2012 and its SSMS.

Location of theese tools are different in file system, logically.

But, when I type in CMD next command: `SSMS.EXE`, and hit Enter, I always get SSMS for 2008 opened.

How can I open SSMS for 2012 using cmd? Is there some option which I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your system path variable is pointing to the 2008 version, either you change it there or you have to use a full qualified path

i.e. c:\installdir2012\ssms.exe

Comment: then remove the 2008 path

Comment: Anyway, you help me a lot, because it was enough just to position SSMS 2012 file path before SSMS 2008, and working OK. I was assuming that system read system variable from first to last, and when it find first  valid path for any SSMS it will open it. Thanks!